# is docker daemon running

Tags: docker, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, dockerfile

I am running jenkins container on kubernetes. for some reason, creating a pipeline that pulls dockerfile from bitbucket and builds an image gives me an error.
The pull stage works fine, the problem is building the image. When I start the pipeline, I get an error saying,

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

I read all the answers and suggestions online but none of them helped.
I tried setting up the global tools, I even added a `mountPath` to `docker.sock` in `values.yaml` file. 
Is there anyone who knows how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

it appears like you are running docker commands from jenkins container. ensure that unix:///var/run/docker.sock is mounted as volume inside jenkins container. Then jenkins would be able to use unix socket to communicate with the docker daemon on the bound host

Comment: I thought adding the mountPath in a value,yaml file does the same thing. Since I am running jankins from using helm chart, I can not add the volume from the command line as most example shows. Is there a way to mount the volume while a container is running?

Comment: one way is to edit the deployment yaml and patch with unix socket mount

Comment: I dont have deployment.yaml file. Only values.yaml and I mount the volume there but it still does not work.

Comment: Check the `ActiveState` of Docker and run `sudo systemctl start docker` if it is in failed state. There are few other things that might help but let us start with that.

Answer (score 0):

Few options:

1. Check the `ActiveState` of Docker and run `systemctl start docker` if it is in failed state.
2. Use `sudo` in case of your current user not having access permissions to communicate with docker daemon.
3. Run `dockerd` - the persistent process that manages containers. Docker
   uses different binaries for the daemon and client.

Please, let me know if that helped.

Comment: These are in addition to @P Ekambaram's answer.